# Bash no such file or directory every time I open the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux terminal, for other purposes I have executed some commands related to adding environment variables(I guess) as follows:

```
echo "source ~[some path]/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

However, during my process of figuring out the right path, I executed the above commands with the wrong path several times before I got it right. Now I think my desired environment variable have been successfully added but those "bad" path have been added and every time I open the terminal I got all those 'bash: xxxx No such file or directory' warning:[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evo2i.png)
It's not a serious bug but I wonder if there is a way I can get rid of them ?
Many thanks!

Comment: Just open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor and delete the extra lines you added

Comment: Try with `echo "source $(echo ~[user])/<relativepath_from_user>/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You've obscured the paths themselves, but I managed to work out that the last file you're trying to load is in the path `~Desktop`, whereas I think you meant `~/Desktop`. In your `.profile` or `.bashrc` files, I'd rather use the env variables, though, and use `$HOME` for paths under my home directory.

Lastly, using `source` is absolutely fine (and POSIX compliant), but seeing as your file is called `.bashrc`, it's safe to assume that you're only targetting bash. To save some typing, bash has `source` aliased to `.` (dot). What I'd write in my bashrc file, then, would be:

```
. "${HOME}/Desktop/path/to/script.sh"
```

This does mean the append echo command you have is probably best changed to use single quotes:

```
echo '. "${HOME}/some/path/setup.sh"'
```

Just keep in mind: having multiple slashes where you only need one (e.g. `/home/foo///bar////path///file.sh`) is safer/better than omitting a required slash (which is what was causing your problem).